# Fitting for constants

Tags: plotting, fitting, physics

I have this differential equation: $$m\ddot x=-kx^\frac{3}{2}-c\dot x-mg$$ where I want to fit for $k$, $c$. ($g$ is 9.81 and $m$ is 0.3).

This is a model for collision, hence in the data that we have collected in our experiment, all we know is that `x'[0]==-3`, where -3 is the impact velocity before the collision, and `x'[T]==2` where 2 is the rebounding velocity after the collision and `T`is the time of contact, which we cannot measure experimentally as it is very short, but we know that it is shorter than $10^{-3}s$.

```
m = 1;
k = 1;
c = 1;
g = 9.81;
sol = NDSolve[ 
  {m x''[t] == -k x[t]^(3/2) - c x'[t] - m g, x'[0] == -3, x[0] == 0.024965, 
   x'[0.00001] == 2},
  x[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

Here is the data.

Data for x against t:

```
{{0.,23.6724},{0.0333333,23.4316},{0.0666667,23.2125},
 {0.1,22.9737},{0.133333,22.7191},{0.166667,22.4796},
 {0.2,22.2635},{0.233333,22.0175},{0.266667,21.7774},
 {0.3,21.5224},{0.333333,21.3139},{0.366667,21.064},
 {0.4,20.8183},{0.433333,20.5699},{0.466667,20.3129},
 {0.5,20.0644},{0.533333,19.8333},{0.566656,19.5862},
 {0.599989,19.3391},{0.633322,19.094},{0.666656,18.8495},
 {0.699989,18.5973},{0.733322,18.3451},{0.766656,18.09},
 {0.799989,17.8299},{0.833322,17.581},{0.866656,17.3204},
 {0.899989,17.0659},{0.933322,16.817},{0.966656,16.5627},
 {0.999989,16.3046},{1.03332,16.0535},{1.06666,15.7956},
 {1.09999,15.5383},{1.13332,15.2806},{1.16666,15.0236},
 {1.19999,14.7635},{1.23332,14.5015},{1.26666,14.2514},
 {1.29999,13.9673},{1.33332,13.6998},{1.36666,13.4402},
 {1.39999,13.1574},{1.43332,12.8848},{1.46666,12.6188},
 {1.49999,12.3376},{1.53332,12.0596},{1.56666,11.7867},
 {1.59999,11.5302},{1.63332,11.2418},{1.66664,10.9721},
 {1.69998,10.7005},{1.73331,10.399},{1.76664,10.1111},
 {1.79998,9.83385},{1.83331,9.56173},{1.86664,9.25114},
 {1.89998,8.98928},{1.93331,8.70041},{1.96664,8.41822},
 {1.99998,8.13319},{2.03331,7.84509},{2.06664,7.53343},
 {2.09998,7.25237},{2.13331,6.95413},{2.16664,6.63875},
 {2.19998,6.34642},{2.23331,6.06828},{2.26664,5.77579},
 {2.29998,5.4747},{2.33331,5.15976},{2.36664,4.84916},
 {2.39998,4.5256},{2.43331,4.22336},{2.46664,3.9177},
 {2.49998,3.58284},{2.53331,3.2908},{2.56664,2.97411},
 {2.59998,2.6861},{2.63331,2.4965},{2.66664,2.73492},
 {2.69998,2.99366},{2.73331,3.29602},{2.76663,3.58096},
 {2.79997,3.83507},{2.8333,4.1179},{2.86663,4.39381},
 {2.89997,4.66047},{2.9333,4.95059},{2.96663,5.23038},
 {2.99997,5.48554},{3.0333,5.77507},{3.06663,6.03556},
 {3.09997,6.30288},{3.1333,6.56806},{3.16663,6.82612},
 {3.19997,7.11681},{3.2333,7.37396},{3.26663,7.63213},
 {3.29997,7.89755},{3.3333,8.15167},{3.36663,8.4428},
 {3.39997,8.6969},{3.4333,8.95516},{3.46663,9.22325},
 {3.49997,9.47407},{3.5333,9.73972},{3.56663,9.98549},
 {3.59997,10.2457},{3.6333,10.4917},{3.66663,10.7494},
 {3.69997,10.9985},{3.7333,11.2493},{3.76663,11.5069},
 {3.79997,11.7599},{3.8333,12.0148},{3.86663,12.2645},
 {3.89996,12.5198},{3.93329,12.7714},{3.96662,13.0222},
 {3.99996,13.2753},{4.03329,13.4973},{4.06662,13.7457},
 {4.09996,13.9856},{4.13329,14.2364},{4.16662,14.4828},
 {4.19996,14.7348},{4.23329,14.9753},{4.26662,15.211},
 {4.29996,15.4466},{4.33329,15.6922},{4.36662,15.9198},
 {4.39996,16.1627},{4.43329,16.4001},{4.46662,16.6353},
 {4.49996,16.8629},{4.53329,17.1011},{4.56662,17.3418},
 {4.59996,17.5674},{4.63329,17.81},{4.66662,18.0313},
 {4.69996,18.2533},{4.73329,18.4823},{4.76662,18.7227},
 {4.79996,18.9488},{4.83329,19.1835},{4.86662,19.4019},
 {4.89996,19.6282},{4.93329,19.86},{4.96662,20.084},
 {4.99994,20.3083},{5.03328,20.5353},{5.06661,20.7602},
 {5.09994,20.9745},{5.13328,21.1844},{5.16661,21.4296},
 {5.19994,21.6461},{5.23328,21.8579},{5.26661,22.0885},
 {5.29994,22.3081},{5.33328,22.5211}}
```

[Take note that x is in cm.](https://www.google.com/search?q=cm%20to%20m)

Most of the data is useless because they are just data for the dropping and bouncing part, not actually the collision.

In the code, I only did `NDSolve` and substitute in random values for $k$, $c$, and also substitute some of the initial conditions like `x[0]==0.024965` , `x'[0]==-3` and `x[T]==2`.

With these, is it possible for us to fit the constants?

Thank you.

Comment: Please post the data you have collected in your experiment.

Comment: Okay sure I will edit the post. But i dont think the data I have collected would be helpful. Because the part that actually matters only take up less than one frame

Comment: Hi sir does it work?

Comment: It can be made to work (to a point), but multiple adjustments have to be made. I will post an answer tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You are using 3 initial conditions for a 2nd order ode!  That seems to be wrong!

Comment: Yes indeed that's just me trying to fit the constants... The code is wrong lol. I am just trying to fit for 2 constants.

Comment: Where did you consider "conservation of momentum" in your model?

Comment: Momentum is not conserved. Coefficient of restitution is not a constant value. Thats why we are using this spring-mass damper- model to account for energy losses

Comment: Looking at your data  something happens(probably the collision?) for `t==2.63331s, x==0.024965m`. This contact point isn't modelled in your ode!

Comment: No my ODE is assuming that when the object barely touches the ground with initial velocity, x=0. Then it will deform in shape, thus "sinking" into the ground where x<0. We are trying to model this deformation depth using the equation.  Also in the question I stated that most of the data is useless because it is really the data for the deformation part as our experimental equipment was not precise enough. Thank you.

Comment: But your data never reaches point x=0?

Comment: Yes thats the problem here haha. Also the object has a finite size, I only tracked down the position of its centre of mass. When it is 0.024965m, it refers to the position of the centre of mass and it is probably touching the ground at this moment

Comment: Oh wait Good catch! The intial condition is wrong. I have edited my initial conditions in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually we can use data to optimise parameters as follows

```
data = {{0., 23.6724}, {0.0333333, 23.4316}, {0.0666667, 23.2125}, {0.1, 22.9737}, {0.133333, 22.7191}, {0.166667, 22.4796}, {0.2, 22.2635}, {0.233333, 22.0175}, {0.266667, 21.7774}, {0.3, 21.5224}, {0.333333, 21.3139}, {0.366667, 21.064}, {0.4, 20.8183}, {0.433333, 20.5699}, {0.466667, 20.3129}, {0.5, 20.0644}, {0.533333, 19.8333}, {0.566656, 19.5862}, {0.599989, 19.3391}, {0.633322, 19.094}, {0.666656, 18.8495}, {0.699989, 18.5973}, {0.733322, 18.3451}, {0.766656, 18.09}, {0.799989, 17.8299}, {0.833322, 17.581}, {0.866656, 17.3204}, {0.899989, 17.0659}, {0.933322, 16.817}, {0.966656, 16.5627}, {0.999989, 16.3046}, {1.03332, 16.0535}, {1.06666, 15.7956}, {1.09999, 15.5383}, {1.13332, 15.2806}, {1.16666, 15.0236}, {1.19999, 14.7635}, {1.23332, 14.5015}, {1.26666, 14.2514}, {1.29999, 13.9673}, {1.33332, 13.6998}, {1.36666, 13.4402}, {1.39999, 13.1574}, {1.43332, 12.8848}, {1.46666, 12.6188}, {1.49999, 12.3376}, {1.53332, 12.0596}, {1.56666, 11.7867}, {1.59999, 11.5302}, {1.63332, 11.2418}, {1.66664, 10.9721}, {1.69998, 10.7005}, {1.73331, 10.399}, {1.76664, 10.1111}, {1.79998, 9.83385}, {1.83331, 9.56173}, {1.86664, 9.25114}, {1.89998, 8.98928}, {1.93331, 8.70041}, {1.96664, 8.41822}, {1.99998, 8.13319}, {2.03331, 7.84509}, {2.06664, 7.53343}, {2.09998, 7.25237}, {2.13331, 6.95413}, {2.16664, 6.63875}, {2.19998, 6.34642}, {2.23331, 6.06828}, {2.26664, 5.77579}, {2.29998, 5.4747}, {2.33331, 5.15976}, {2.36664, 4.84916}, {2.39998, 4.5256}, {2.43331, 4.22336}, {2.46664, 3.9177}, {2.49998, 3.58284}, {2.53331, 3.2908}, {2.56664, 2.97411}, {2.59998, 2.6861}, {2.63331, 2.4965}, {2.66664, 2.73492}, {2.69998, 2.99366}, {2.73331, 3.29602}, {2.76663, 3.58096}, {2.79997, 3.83507}, {2.8333, 4.1179}, {2.86663, 4.39381}, {2.89997, 4.66047}, {2.9333, 4.95059}, {2.96663, 5.23038}, {2.99997, 5.48554}, {3.0333, 5.77507}, {3.06663, 6.03556}, {3.09997, 6.30288}, {3.1333, 6.56806}, {3.16663, 6.82612}, {3.19997, 7.11681}, {3.2333, 7.37396}, {3.26663, 7.63213}, {3.29997, 7.89755}, {3.3333, 8.15167}, {3.36663, 8.4428}, {3.39997, 8.6969}, {3.4333, 8.95516}, {3.46663, 9.22325}, {3.49997, 9.47407}, {3.5333, 9.73972}, {3.56663, 9.98549}, {3.59997, 10.2457}, {3.6333, 10.4917}, {3.66663, 10.7494}, {3.69997, 10.9985}, {3.7333, 11.2493}, {3.76663, 11.5069}, {3.79997, 11.7599}, {3.8333, 12.0148}, {3.86663, 12.2645}, {3.89996, 12.5198}, {3.93329, 12.7714}, {3.96662, 13.0222}, {3.99996, 13.2753}, {4.03329, 13.4973}, {4.06662, 13.7457}, {4.09996, 13.9856}, {4.13329, 14.2364}, {4.16662, 14.4828}, {4.19996, 14.7348}, {4.23329, 14.9753}, {4.26662, 15.211}, {4.29996, 15.4466}, {4.33329, 15.6922}, {4.36662, 15.9198}, {4.39996, 16.1627}, {4.43329, 16.4001}, {4.46662, 16.6353}, {4.49996, 16.8629}, {4.53329, 17.1011}, {4.56662, 17.3418}, {4.59996, 17.5674}, {4.63329, 17.81}, {4.66662, 18.0313}, {4.69996, 18.2533}, {4.73329, 18.4823}, {4.76662, 18.7227}, {4.79996, 18.9488}, {4.83329, 19.1835}, {4.86662, 19.4019}, {4.89996, 19.6282}, {4.93329, 19.86}, {4.96662, 20.084}, {4.99994, 20.3083}, {5.03328, 20.5353}, {5.06661, 20.7602}, {5.09994, 20.9745}, {5.13328, 21.1844}, {5.16661, 21.4296}, {5.19994, 21.6461}, {5.23328, 21.8579}, {5.26661, 22.0885}, {5.29994, 22.3081}, {5.33328, 22.5211}};
```

Now we can use interpolation function `f = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 4]` to find out dependence of acceleration on `x` and `x'` as

```
{ParametricPlot[{f[t], f''[t]}, {t, 2.55, 2.7}, PlotRange -> All, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/2, AxesLabel -> {"x", "x''"}], 
 ParametricPlot[{f'[t], f''[t]}, {t, 2.3, 2.8}, PlotRange -> All, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/2, AxesLabel -> {"x'", "x''"}]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

It looks like typical elastic-plastic deformation, and therefore the Hertz model is not applicable at all. Now we can propose force before and after collision in a form
$$F/m=-k_1 x+k_2 x^2 + k_3 \dot {x}+k_4 \dot {x}^2-g $$
Finally, using `f[t]` we can optimize model in several points, for example,

```
g=981.; param = Table[{t, 
   NMinimize[{(f''[t] + g - k1 f[t] + k2 f[t]^2 + k3 f'[t] + 
        k4 f'[t]^2)^2, k1 > 0 && k2 > 0 && k3 > 0 && k4 > 0}, {k1, k2,
      k3, k4}]}, {t, 2.51, 2.7, .01}]
```

From this table we see that parameters of the model drastically change after collision at `t=2.63`

```
{ListLinePlot[
  Table[{param[[i, 1]], k1 /. param[[i, 2, 2]]}, {i, Length[param]}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "k1"}], 
 ListLinePlot[
  Table[{param[[i, 1]], k2 /. param[[i, 2, 2]]}, {i, Length[param]}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "k2"}], 
 ListLinePlot[
  Table[{param[[i, 1]], k3 /. param[[i, 2, 2]]}, {i, Length[param]}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "k3"}], 
 ListLinePlot[
  Table[{param[[i, 1]], k4 /. param[[i, 2, 2]]}, {i, Length[param]}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "k4"}, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Very nice/interesting!

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful! :)

Comment: I have a few question:
1. Why is hertz contact model not applicable here?
2. I run the same code in mathematica, (just copy pasted the code in your answer), but the t-axis of my graphs of k against t is extremely small, and graphs of k1,k2,and k4 are all empty. May I know why is that so?

Comment: @bobthelegend 1) the Hertz model describes elastic collision, and in this case we have elastic-plastic deformation (see functions `x''[x], x''[x']`; 2) what version do you run? Let try to evaluate `param // TableForm` and check first line in the table. Did you see `k1 -> 241.097  k2 -> 185.712  k3 -> 1048.46 k4 -> 89.1876 ` ?

Comment: No... It outputs: {8.27181*10^-25, {k1 -> 447.611, k2 -> 317.74, k3 -> 1201.73, 
  k4 -> 104.398}}. All I did was copy paste the code included in your answer, and added a g=9.81; at the front. what is wrong here? (´･ω･`)?

Comment: @bobthelegend I see that you made typo we discussed with Anton. Do you understand your upload `data` is in cm and you take $g=9.81 m/s^2$? :)    Just put  `g=981` and please report what you get.

Comment: I got this "{8.10381*10^-20, {k1 -> 244.024, k2 -> 186.606, k3 -> 1066.27, 
  k4 -> 88.7134}". Still nothing in graphs for k1,k3 and k4. k2 is just a bunch of messy lines haha.

Comment: @bobthelegend I have tested code with versions 12.0.0.0 and 12.1.1.0. What version do you run?

Comment: It says mathematica 12.1. I think the values that i get is actually quite close to what you got? just that the graphs wont really plot anything

Comment: @bobthelegend Ah, I am very sorry, code been  updated. Please, take new `param`.

Comment: Yay it works now, thanks so much. Just curious why didnt it work just now?

Comment: @bobthelegend I have several `param` in the code. The last one with time 't' adding, so it works with visualization code. Thank you for your repot.

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm a little bit late, but I want to show how to solve the physical problem straighforward, based on the measurement `tx`  (in units `s,m` !)

```
tx = Map[{#[[1]], #[[2]]/100} &,
{{0., 23.6724}, {0.0333333,23.4316}, {0.0666667, 23.2125}, {0.1, 22.9737}, {0.133333, 22.7191}, {0.166667, 22.4796}, {0.2, 22.2635}, {0.233333,22.0175}, {0.266667, 21.7774}, {0.3, 21.5224}, {0.333333,21.3139}, {0.366667, 21.064}, {0.4, 20.8183}, {0.433333,20.5699}, {0.466667, 20.3129}, {0.5, 20.0644}, {0.533333,19.8333}, {0.566656, 19.5862}, {0.599989, 19.3391}, {0.633322,19.094}, {0.666656, 18.8495}, {0.699989, 18.5973}, {0.733322,18.3451}, {0.766656, 18.09}, {0.799989, 17.8299}, {0.833322,17.581}, {0.866656, 17.3204}, {0.899989, 17.0659}, {0.933322,16.817}, {0.966656, 16.5627}, {0.999989, 16.3046}, {1.03332,16.0535}, {1.06666, 15.7956}, {1.09999, 15.5383}, {1.13332,15.2806}, {1.16666, 15.0236}, {1.19999, 14.7635}, {1.23332,14.5015}, {1.26666, 14.2514}, {1.29999, 13.9673}, {1.33332,13.6998}, {1.36666, 13.4402}, {1.39999, 13.1574}, {1.43332,12.8848}, {1.46666, 12.6188}, {1.49999, 12.3376}, {1.53332,12.0596}, {1.56666, 11.7867}, {1.59999, 11.5302}, {1.63332,11.2418}, {1.66664, 10.9721}, {1.69998, 10.7005}, {1.73331,10.399}, {1.76664, 10.1111}, {1.79998, 9.83385}, {1.83331,9.56173}, {1.86664, 9.25114}, {1.89998, 8.98928}, {1.93331,8.70041}, {1.96664, 8.41822}, {1.99998, 8.13319}, {2.03331,7.84509}, {2.06664, 7.53343}, {2.09998, 7.25237}, {2.13331,6.95413}, {2.16664, 6.63875}, {2.19998, 6.34642}, {2.23331,6.06828}, {2.26664, 5.77579}, {2.29998, 5.4747}, {2.33331, 5.15976}, {2.36664, 4.84916}, {2.39998, 4.5256}, {2.43331,4.22336}, {2.46664, 3.9177}, {2.49998, 3.58284}, {2.53331,3.2908}, {2.56664, 2.97411}, {2.59998, 2.6861}, {2.63331, 2.4965}, {2.66664, 2.73492}, {2.69998, 2.99366}, {2.73331, 3.29602}, {2.76663, 3.58096}, {2.79997, 3.83507}, {2.8333,4.1179}, {2.86663, 4.39381}, {2.89997, 4.66047}, {2.9333, 4.95059}, {2.96663, 5.23038}, {2.99997, 5.48554}, {3.0333, 5.77507}, {3.06663, 6.03556}, {3.09997, 6.30288}, {3.1333,6.56806}, {3.16663, 6.82612}, {3.19997, 7.11681}, {3.2333,7.37396}, {3.26663, 7.63213}, {3.29997, 7.89755}, {3.3333, 8.15167}, {3.36663, 8.4428}, {3.39997, 8.6969}, {3.4333,8.95516}, {3.46663, 9.22325}, {3.49997, 9.47407}, {3.5333,9.73972}, {3.56663, 9.98549}, {3.59997, 10.2457}, {3.6333,10.4917}, {3.66663, 10.7494}, {3.69997, 10.9985}, {3.7333,11.2493}, {3.76663, 11.5069}, {3.79997, 11.7599}, {3.8333,12.0148}, {3.86663, 12.2645}, {3.89996, 12.5198}, {3.93329,12.7714}, {3.96662, 13.0222}, {3.99996, 13.2753}, {4.03329,13.4973}, {4.06662, 13.7457}, {4.09996, 13.9856}, {4.13329,14.2364}, {4.16662, 14.4828}, {4.19996, 14.7348}, {4.23329,14.9753}, {4.26662, 15.211}, {4.29996, 15.4466}, {4.33329,15.6922}, {4.36662, 15.9198}, {4.39996, 16.1627}, {4.43329,16.4001}, {4.46662, 16.6353}, {4.49996, 16.8629}, {4.53329,17.1011}, {4.56662, 17.3418}, {4.59996, 17.5674}, {4.63329,17.81}, {4.66662, 18.0313}, {4.69996, 18.2533}, {4.73329,18.4823}, {4.76662, 18.7227}, {4.79996, 18.9488}, {4.83329,19.1835}, {4.86662, 19.4019}, {4.89996, 19.6282}, {4.93329,19.86}, {4.96662, 20.084}, {4.99994, 20.3083}, {5.03328,20.5353}, {5.06661, 20.7602}, {5.09994, 20.9745}, {5.13328, 21.1844}, {5.16661, 21.4296}, {5.19994, 21.6461}, {5.23328,21.8579}, {5.26661, 22.0885}, {5.29994, 22.3081}, {5.33328,22.5211}}];
```

The measurement shows, where/when the collision takes place

```
{tc, xc} = MinimalBy[tx, Last][[1]];
(*{2.63331, 0.024965}*)
```

The collision (which isn't measured!) is described by the restitution coefficient `x'[SuperPlus[tc]]==-e x'[ SuperMinus[tc]]`

Modified system (only describes the state before/after the collision)  `x''[t] == -F - km x[t]   - cm*x'[t]` can be solved piecewise

```
(*before collision*)
X0 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{ x''[t] == -F - km x[t]   - cm*x'[t] , 
x'[tc] == v0 , x[tc] == xc}, x, {t, tx[[1, 1]], tc}, { v0, F, km, cm , e }]

(*after collision*)
X1 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{ x''[t] == -F - km x[t]   - cm*x'[t] , 
x'[tc] == -v0 e, x[tc] == xc}, x, {t, tc, tx[[-1, 1]]}, { v0, F, km, cm, e  }]
```

system identification

```
mod=NonlinearModelFit[tx, {Which[t <= tc, X0[v0, F, km, cm , e ][t],t > tc, X1[v0, F, km, cm , e ][t]], 0 < e < 1, F > 0, km > 0,cm > 0}, 
{v0, F, km, cm , e}, t, Method -> "NMinimize"]
```

shows

```
Show[{ListPlot[tx, PlotStyle -> Red],Plot[mod[t], {t, 0, tx[[-1, 1]]}]}]
```

[image]

very good agreement with the measurement and justfies the use of a different modell.

Comment: (+1) Yeah, pretty straightforward, after seeing this. :)

Comment: @AntonAntonov Thanks!  But I'm unsure wether it makes sense to additional modell the collision in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

- *This answer does not take into account all details about units and modeled process given by OP.*

  - *Hence it should be* ***seen as "in principle" answer.***
- *It seems that:*

  - *Further descriptions of the process and model are needed*
  - *Multiple modifications of the model and its coding have to be made*
- *Please see the comments to the question and this answer.*

---

Here is the measured data:

```
lsData = {{0., 23.6724}, {0.0333333, 23.4316}, {0.0666667, 23.2125}, {0.1, 22.9737}, {0.133333, 22.7191}, {0.166667, 22.4796}, {0.2, 22.2635}, {0.233333, 22.0175}, {0.266667, 21.7774}, {0.3, 21.5224}, {0.333333, 21.3139}, {0.366667, 21.064}, {0.4, 20.8183}, {0.433333, 20.5699}, {0.466667, 20.3129}, {0.5, 20.0644}, {0.533333, 19.8333}, {0.566656, 19.5862}, {0.599989, 19.3391}, {0.633322, 19.094}, {0.666656, 18.8495}, {0.699989, 18.5973}, {0.733322, 18.3451}, {0.766656, 18.09}, {0.799989, 17.8299}, {0.833322, 17.581}, {0.866656, 17.3204}, {0.899989, 17.0659}, {0.933322, 16.817}, {0.966656, 16.5627}, {0.999989, 16.3046}, {1.03332, 16.0535}, {1.06666, 15.7956}, {1.09999, 15.5383}, {1.13332, 15.2806}, {1.16666, 15.0236}, {1.19999, 14.7635}, {1.23332, 14.5015}, {1.26666, 14.2514}, {1.29999, 13.9673}, {1.33332, 13.6998}, {1.36666, 13.4402}, {1.39999, 13.1574}, {1.43332, 12.8848}, {1.46666, 12.6188}, {1.49999, 12.3376}, {1.53332, 12.0596}, {1.56666, 11.7867}, {1.59999, 11.5302}, {1.63332, 11.2418}, {1.66664, 10.9721}, {1.69998, 10.7005}, {1.73331, 10.399}, {1.76664, 10.1111}, {1.79998, 9.83385}, {1.83331, 9.56173}, {1.86664, 9.25114}, {1.89998, 8.98928}, {1.93331, 8.70041}, {1.96664, 8.41822}, {1.99998, 8.13319}, {2.03331, 7.84509}, {2.06664, 7.53343}, {2.09998, 7.25237}, {2.13331, 6.95413}, {2.16664, 6.63875}, {2.19998, 6.34642}, {2.23331, 6.06828}, {2.26664, 5.77579}, {2.29998, 5.4747}, {2.33331, 5.15976}, {2.36664, 4.84916}, {2.39998, 4.5256}, {2.43331, 4.22336}, {2.46664, 3.9177}, {2.49998, 3.58284}, {2.53331, 3.2908}, {2.56664, 2.97411}, {2.59998, 2.6861}, {2.63331, 2.4965}, {2.66664, 2.73492}, {2.69998, 2.99366}, {2.73331, 3.29602}, {2.76663, 3.58096}, {2.79997, 3.83507}, {2.8333, 4.1179}, {2.86663, 4.39381}, {2.89997, 4.66047}, {2.9333, 4.95059}, {2.96663, 5.23038}, {2.99997, 5.48554}, {3.0333, 5.77507}, {3.06663, 6.03556}, {3.09997, 6.30288}, {3.1333, 6.56806}, {3.16663, 6.82612}, {3.19997, 7.11681}, {3.2333, 7.37396}, {3.26663, 7.63213}, {3.29997, 7.89755}, {3.3333, 8.15167}, {3.36663, 8.4428}, {3.39997, 8.6969}, {3.4333, 8.95516}, {3.46663, 9.22325}, {3.49997, 9.47407}, {3.5333, 9.73972}, {3.56663, 9.98549}, {3.59997, 10.2457}, {3.6333, 10.4917}, {3.66663, 10.7494}, {3.69997, 10.9985}, {3.7333, 11.2493}, {3.76663, 11.5069}, {3.79997, 11.7599}, {3.8333, 12.0148}, {3.86663, 12.2645}, {3.89996, 12.5198}, {3.93329, 12.7714}, {3.96662, 13.0222}, {3.99996, 13.2753}, {4.03329, 13.4973}, {4.06662, 13.7457}, {4.09996, 13.9856}, {4.13329, 14.2364}, {4.16662, 14.4828}, {4.19996, 14.7348}, {4.23329, 14.9753}, {4.26662, 15.211}, {4.29996, 15.4466}, {4.33329, 15.6922}, {4.36662, 15.9198}, {4.39996, 16.1627}, {4.43329, 16.4001}, {4.46662, 16.6353}, {4.49996, 16.8629}, {4.53329, 17.1011}, {4.56662, 17.3418}, {4.59996, 17.5674}, {4.63329, 17.81}, {4.66662, 18.0313}, {4.69996, 18.2533}, {4.73329, 18.4823}, {4.76662, 18.7227}, {4.79996, 18.9488}, {4.83329, 19.1835}, {4.86662, 19.4019}, {4.89996, 19.6282}, {4.93329, 19.86}, {4.96662, 20.084}, {4.99994, 20.3083}, {5.03328, 20.5353}, {5.06661, 20.7602}, {5.09994, 20.9745}, {5.13328, 21.1844}, {5.16661, 21.4296}, {5.19994, 21.6461}, {5.23328, 21.8579}, {5.26661, 22.0885}, {5.29994, 22.3081}, {5.33328, 22.5211}};
```

---

Below the ODE model programming is changed in several ways:

- Using `RealAbs` for `x[t]`
- Adding `WhenEvent` for dealing with the bouncing
- Using the first x-value of the measurements data to make an initial condition
- Using parametric formulation for the family of solutions parameterized with `k` and `c`

```
ClearAll[g, m, k, c];
m = 0.3;
g = 9.81;
sol = 
  ParametricNDSolve[{
    m*x''[t] == -k*RealAbs[x[t]]^(3/2) - c*x'[t] - g*m, 
    WhenEvent[x[t] == 0, x'[t] -> -2/3 x'[t]], 
    x'[0] == -3, 
    x[0] == lsData[[1, 2]] 
   }, x, {t, Min[lsData[[All, 1]]], Max[lsData[[All, 1]]]}, {k, c}]
```

[image]

**Remark:**

- > [...] all we know is that x'[0]==-3, where -3 is the impact velocity before the collision, and x'[T]==2 where 2 is the rebounding velocity after the collision and T is the time of contact, [...]
- `WhenEvent[x[t] == 0, x'[t] -> -2/3 x'[t]]` says that when the object touches the ground it bounces (with opposite in sign) velocity that is $2/3$-rds of the velocity just before impact. (The $2/3$ coefficient comes from the velocities described in the question.)

---

Here we define a function `ParDist` that measures the deviation of the fit (that takes as arguments parametric function, parameters list, measured data):

```
Clear[ParDist]
ParDist[x_ParametricFunction, {k_?NumberQ, c_?NumberQ}, tsPath : {{_?NumberQ, _?NumberQ} ..}] := 
   Block[{points, tMin, tMax}, 
    points = Map[{#, x[k, c][#]} &, tsPath[[All, 1]]]; 
    Norm[(tsPath[[All, 2]] - Re[points[[All, 2]]])/tsPath[[All, 2]]] 
   ];
```

---

Minimize the measure function ParDist over an appropriate domain for the parameters:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
  nsol = NMinimize[{ParDist[x /. sol, {k, c}, lsData], -1 <= k <= 0, -2 <= c <= 0}, {k, c}, Method -> "NelderMead", PrecisionGoal -> 3, AccuracyGoal -> 3, MaxIterations -> 100] 
 ]

(* Messages... *)

(*{0.319493, {2.57776, {k -> -0.0223514, c -> -0.0730673}}}*)
```

*(Several experiments can/should be done with different parameter ranges.)*

---

Evaluate the parametric function with the found parameters over the domain of the measured data and plot:

```
Block[{k, c}, 
   {k, c} = {k, c} /. nsol[[2]]; 
   fitData = Table[{t, Re[x[k, c][t] /. sol]}, {t, lsData[[All, 1]]}] 
  ];
ListPlot[{lsData, fitData}, PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> "Detailed",PlotLegends -> {"Measured", "Fitted"}]
```

[image]

---

Similar, but more complicated procedure is described in
[this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/190295)
of
["Model calibration with phase space data"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/190232).

Comment: Sorry I think you might have misunderstood my question. The data that I provided was not very useful as we would want to model the instant of collision instead of the entire bouncing motion of the object.

Comment: My ODE is basically saying that when the object barely touches the ground with some initial velocity v, x=0. The object will then deform in shape, thus "sinking" into the ground where x<0. We are trying to model this deformation depth using the equation. All we know is the velocity at the start, and the velocity at the end. We know roughly what the time of contact is but still unsure.

Comment: But thank you anyways because the answer is still very useful as you have taught me the basic method for fitting the data :)

Comment: @bobthelegend First -- you are welcome! Second, you have to modify and reprogram your model according to your descriptions in the comments above. For example, you can modify the `WhenEvent` part to fit better the "interaction" with the ground.

Comment: "WhenEvent[x[t] == 0, x'[t] -> -2/3 x'[t]", what does this line mean? Thanks

Comment: (I think I explained it in my last answer update...) `WhenEvent[x[t] == 0, x'[t] -> -2/3 x'[t]]` says that when the object touches the ground it bounces (with opposite in sign) velocity that is 2/3-rds of the velocity just before impact. (The 2/3 coefficient comes from velocities you described in your question.)

Comment: @AntonAntonov It is not clear, how you correlated data for `x` given in cm with equation where free fall acceleration is given in SI unit $g=9.81 m/s^2$? :)

Comment: @AlexTrounev Very good point! I knew about the units, but forgot to adjust for that after seeing that the fitting more or less worked...

Comment: @AlexTrounev I added an "intro" to my answer that basically says, "Aah! Units! I give up..." :)

Comment: @AntonAntonov It's ok and (+1) for optimization. Actually we can neglect by `g` in this problem or use it as parameter to be optimized too.

Answer (score 2):

This is an extension for the excellent answer from @Ulrich Neumann considering

$$m\ddot x=-kx^{\alpha}-c\dot x-mg$$ instead of

$$m\ddot x=-kx-c\dot x-mg$$

```
tx = Map[{#[[1]], #[[2]]/100} &, data]
{tc, xc} = MinimalBy[tx, Last][[1]];

X0 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x''[t] == -F - km Sign[x[t]] Abs[x[t]]^alpha - cm*x'[t], x'[tc] == v0, x[tc] == xc}, x, {t, tx[[1, 1]], tc}, {v0, F, km, cm, alpha, e}]
X1 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x''[t] == -F - km Sign[x[t]] Abs[x[t]]^alpha - cm*x'[t], x'[tc] == -v0 e, x[tc] == xc}, x, {t, tc, tx[[-1, 1]]}, {v0, F, km, cm, alpha, e}]

mod = NonlinearModelFit[tx, {Which[t <= tc, X0[v0, F, km, cm, alpha, e][t], t > tc, X1[v0, F, km, cm, alpha, e][t]], 0 < e < 1, F > 0, km > 0, cm > 0, 0.5 < alpha < 3}, {v0, F, km, cm, alpha, e}, t, Method -> "NMinimize"]

Show[{ListPlot[tx, PlotStyle -> Red], Plot[mod[t], {t, 0, tx[[-1, 1]]}]}]

Normal[mod]
```

[image]